# Writing a program for a report card by entering the student's name and their respective marks by using key values generated by the user in dictionary

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, user-input

i wrote this code exactly shown in the youtube by the person.But he got the output and when I executed the code my syntax is error.whats the solution

Comment: Where's the code? Please copy/paste and format the code that causes the error. Be as complete as possible.

Comment: I got the answer bro
Thanks 